# Writing an ajax variable to txt file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a facebook application coded client side and I want to store the tokens on my server for later use

There is a variable called 'token' and I then create a new function called 'apple' to write this variable in a json format to a txt file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(){

    //access token stuff
    var token = $("#link_input").val();
    //alert("Got Token: " + token + ". your application token");

    if (token.split('#access_token=')[1]) {
    var token = token.split('#access_token=')[1].split('&')[0];
    //alert(token);



function WriteToFile(apple)
    {
    $.post("save.php",{ 'token': apple },
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        }, "text"
    );
    return false;
    }
```

My php file

```
<?php
$thefile = "new.json"; /* Our filename as defined earlier */
$towrite = $_POST["token"]; /* What we'll write to the file */
echo $towrite;
$openedfile = fopen($thefile, "w");
$encoded = json_encode($towrite);
fwrite($openedfile, $encoded);
fclose($openedfile);
return "<br> <br>".$towrite;

?>
```

but i cant get it to write anything

Comment: 1/ chmod? 2/ try: `fopen($thefile, "w+")` 3/ error_log?

Comment: Well... you never call your `WriteToFile` function within your javascript.

Comment: check the value returned from your `fopen` call. If it failed to open the file, it will return `false` instead of a file handle.

Comment: @user1847757 it never gets that far as the `$.post` is never executed. In the JS, `WriteToFile` may be defined, but, again, it is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands now, you define your `WriteToFile` function in JS, but you *never* call it.
Change your JS to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        //access token stuff
        var token = $("#link_input").val();
        //alert("Got Token: " + token + ". your application token");

        if (token.split('#access_token=')[1]) {
            var token = token.split('#access_token=')[1].split('&')[0];
            WriteToFile(token);
        }
    }



    function WriteToFile(apple) {
        $.post("save.php",{ 'token': apple },
            function(data){
                alert(data);
            }, "text");
        return false;
    }

};
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        //access token stuff
        var token = $("#link_input").val();
        //alert("Got Token: " + token + ". your application token");

        if (token.split('#access_token=')[1]) {
            var token = token.split('#access_token=')[1].split('&')[0];
            $.post("save.php",{ 'token': token }, function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }, "text");
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first create the file in the location and then set the right permissions or the PHP will not be able to write it.

Comment: i create a new.json file with 666 permissions. but nothing writes to it